# Efficient way to get all substrings from a string that contains special characters

Tags: c++, string, boost

I have got a string like this:

```
    std::string input = "This* #is # #just# a *random ##string #*that# 
may contain any# char*cters#";
```

I need to get all substrings that:

**1) Between character '#'**

**AND**

**2) Contain character '*'**

The result will be:

```
" a *random "
"*that"
" char*cters"
```

I do it like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> substrings;
boost::split(substrings, input, boost::is_any_of("#"));
for (int i = 0; i < substrings.size(); i++)
{
if (i != 0 // first and last substring is not between '#' (only from one side)
   && (i != substrings.size() - 1) 
   && !substrings[i].empty() 
   && substrings[i].find('*') != std::string::npos) // if contain '*' character
   {
      // Here I've got my result
   }
}
```

It works, but is there any efficient solutions to do this ?

Comment: If you want to do that with less code, a regex lib is what you need. If you want to do that with less cpu time, you should iterate the string with your own code to split.

Comment: In your code, if you start your loop at `1` and end at `substrings.size() - 1`, you don't need these 2 conditions in loop. And as empty string doesn't contains '*', you may also remove the `empty` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [regular expression](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) `"#([^#*]*[*][^#]*)#"` to extract all such strings.

The expression describes the kind of substrings that you are looking for:

- Start in a `#`
- Has zero or more characters other than an asterisk,...
- which is followed by at least one asterisk
- which is followed by zero or more characters other than `#`
- which is followed by `#` at the end.

Comment: Should it be `"#([^#*]*[*][^#*]*)#"` (for exactly 1 `'*'` and no `'#'` inside) ? or `"#([^#*]*[*][^#]*)#"` (for 1+ `'*'` and no `'#'` inside) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, you are absolutely right - my expression could grab strings with `#`s in it, which isn't what OP wants. Thanks for the correction!